# Protect ASP.NET Source code

Tags: asp.net, deployment, obfuscation

Im currently doing some research in how to best protect my source code so that no external parties can view and use my code.

From browsing the web a few ideas have come to mind i.e

1) Publish website into a DLL

2) Code obfuscator

3) 3rd Party

But none i find are really explained that well or shown in detail how to achieve this. Anyone here who could shed some more light on this topic ?

Thanks in advance