# Server-Side-Code in aspx file

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle

I want to ask in which phase of Control Execution Lifecycle is the "**Server-Side-Code written in aspx file"** being executed?

Is it before SaveState or after, I claim it's in the rendering phase, is it true??

in aspx file if my code writen as

"<%"

```
if(true)
{
rdlistAnswers.Items.Clear();
foreach (string item in myCollection)
{
    i.Value = item;
    i.Text = item;
    rdlistAnswers.Items.Add(i);
}
"%>"
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlistAnswers" runat="server"</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

the changes made to the are rendered but not saved.
but when write the tag as

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdlistAnswers" runat="server" OnPreRender="loadMe"</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

-as loadMe is an event handler method in the aspx.cs file makes the same thing as code above- the changes are rendered and saved, so when I do changes in PreRender phase the state is saved but when I do it by placing the logic in the aspx file its not saved, this means -at least as I claim- that server-side code placed in aspx file executes in rendering phase, do you agree me???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code written directly inside the aspx file will be executed at the end of **[Render Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.render.aspx) in the ASP.NET page lifecycle**.

I tested it [precompiling an aspx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413246/protect-asp-net-source-code#413272) and [using Reflector to look at the decompiled code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265295/-net-decompilation-how-easy-is-it#265315).

Comment: Ok, I noticed that when I'm tracing my code, but for POC I'm serching for an article explains code execution cycle in asp.net, didn't you saw one??

Comment: Well, there is the MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx and Best Practices here: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/ASP.NET-Life-Cycle-and-Best-Practices/ and another one here: http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020102.htm